# why this code make infinite loop

Tags: c++, arrays, char

i'm trying to test many of test cases for minesweeper game
and it causes infinte loop and i didn't get the output

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m ;

    //cout<<"bug1";
    char grid[n+2][m+2] ;
    string numbers="0123456789" ;
    memset(grid,'0',sizeof grid);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            cin>>grid[i][j];

    //cout<<"bug2";


    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
            if(grid[i][j]!='*'){
                int counter=0;
                for(int ii=i-1;ii<i+2;ii++){
                    for(int jj=j-1;j<j+2;jj++){
                        if(ii>=0 && jj>=0 && grid[ii][jj]=='*')
                            counter++;
                    }
                }
                grid[i][j]=numbers[counter];
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
            cout<<grid[i][j] ;
        }
        cout<<endl ;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

i try this test case

[image]

and it causes infinte loop so ...what is the solution ?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: i'm trying to debug this code more than  1 hour and i don't know why it causes infinte loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
j<j+2 // in for(int jj=j-1;j<j+2;jj++){
```

is always true, the result is infinite loop.

Using `real` variables like `count`, `total` etc makes sense here considering your choice of variables :

```
i,n,j,m,ii,jj // No wonder if someone is not confused with this.
```

to name a few.

Comment: And this is why using meaningful variable names helps.  Looks like a typo(`j` instead of `jj`).

Comment: Better not use the SO users as your debuggers ;) I agree with @NathanOliver's  suggestion to use a debugger.

Comment: @Khaledooz : You may accept the answer if it helped. :)

Comment: @Khaledooz : I didn't downvote the question, but the downvoter might have thought that you could have fixed your code by stepping through a debugger.

Comment: i try so hard to find the bug
but my eye didn't here this small difference in the condition 
@NathanOliver

Comment: @Khaledooz : That is why you need to use a debugger like `gdb`.